# What is the difference in passing parameter of action with id or empid in mvc?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm new in MVC framework. I have a little confusion of passing a parameter **Name** in action.
This is my Employee class:

```
namespace TestApplication.Models
{
    [Table ("Employee")]
    public class Employee
    {
        public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string City { get; set; }
        public int DepartmentId { get; set; }
    }
}
```

This is my Controller:

```
namespace TestApplication.Controllers
{
    public class EmployeeController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /Employee/
        public ActionResult Details(int **empid**)
        {
            EmployeeContext employeecontext = new EmployeeContext();
            Employee employee = employeecontext.employees.Single(emp => emp.EmployeeId == id);
            return View(employee);
        }
    }
}
```

This is my Details View:

```
@model  TestApplication.Models.Employee 
<div style="font-family :Arial">
    <h2>Employees Details</h2>
    <table style="font-family:Arial ">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <b>Employee Id:</b>
            </td>
            <td>
                @Model.EmployeeId
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <b>Employee Name:</b>
            </td>
            <td>
                @Model.Name
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <b>Employee City:</b>
            </td>
            <td>
                @Model.City
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

In this code when I run this application with **/Employee/Details/1**
then it gives me an error like

> The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'empid'
>   of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method
>   'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult Details(Int32)' in
>   'TestApplication.Controllers.EmployeeController'. An optional
>   parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as
>   an optional parameter. Parameter name: parameters

but when I use id as the parameter name in action then it will run perfectly, so what is the difference? How would I choose parameter Name?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Look at your default MVC route in `App_Start/RouteConfig.cs`, it will say something like this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

This is saying that if you pass a URL like `/Employee/Details/1` then the value of `1` will be parameter name of `id` so doesn't map to `empid`. You can eithe:

1. Add another route to allow `empid`
2. Rename `empid` to `id`
3. Use old style url: `/Employee/Details?empid=1`

Comment: hi have you see there is new controller named employee and there is not used any route so i thing this is not a solution which you give, sorry i am not good as you but can this default route is effact in all other custom controller which made by user?

Comment: @Vinit_Patel You are mistaken. The route I show only says `Home` is the default controller if one is not specified in the URL. However, the URL says `Employee`.

Comment: see here /Employee/Details/1    Employee is controller and Details is action (get) and 1 is parameter , now in action if write id then it's receive that 1 value but if write any other mane like int empid then it's throw an error you can see

Comment: @Vinit_Patel Correct, you need to choose one of the actions in my answer to fix it.

Answer (score 3):

In your `RouteConfig` you may have defined as below;

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

So third parameter name should be `id`.

You can try as below;

```
 /Employee/Details?empid=1
```